# Does RDS SQL Server support running python script?

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-rds

I am trying execute Python script from RDS SQL Server 15 version but I didn't find any documentation around this in AWS  Will it be possible to do this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What would the Python script do? You should probably rethink your system architecture if you need to execute Python scripts on RDS instances.

Comment: Vasek - I want to connect RDS SQL Server to run "select" on one table in AWS lambda.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that is not possible as of now. RDS for SQL Server is just Relational Database Service and it does not allow you to execute any program on the RDS instance, except for T-SQL programmability stored within your SQL Server database (triggers, stored procedures, etc).

Comment: Thanks vasek. Is it only for RDS SQL or even for RDS MySQL also we cannot run "select/insert/etc" queries from lambda using any python/ any script?

Comment: Yes, we dont have direct APIs to query SQL. For this with the help of odbc package we can we query. Details found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65663732/how-to-run-rds-sql-server-select-queries-in-aws-lambda-using-boto3-rds-client-py